# How to get input from user in IBM jacl scripting?

Tags: wsadmin, jacl

`I need to get the input from the user and display the value using IBM wsadmin scripting as jacl scripting language. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please elaborate the scenario. JACL helps you to "silently" automate tasks on the AS. Why will you need user input for a automation script ?

Comment: Yes I know it.. I need to configure the plugin properties using jacl scripting.. As per requirements some of the properties need user interaction for that scenario.. How can i manage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the code and it works for me

`puts "Enter the Value:"
set input [gets stdin]
puts "input value ::$input"`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking to have the user supply the input as command line parameters (rather than interactively during the execution of the script), refer to the following knowledge center page,
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cxml_jacl.html

from which the following section is copied:

The Jacl shells pass the command-line arguments to the script as the value of the argv variable. The number of command-line arguments is given by argc variable. The name of the program, or script, is not part of argv nor is it counted by argc. The argv variable is a list. Use the lindex command to extract items from the argument list, for example:

```
set  first  [lindex  $argv  0]
set  second  [lindex  $argv  1]
```